# Must I use iOS in-app purchases for a service billing with variable amount each month?

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, in-app-billing

The service is for a digital option within the app but users are to be billed on a monthly basis, based on the activity they have actually made. 
How do I make sure my app isn't rejected?

Comment: can you please give some more idea regarding your application flow?

Comment: The app provides the user with basic functionality up between the app owner and other users up to a maximum number of other users. Then it asks to user to put in his credit card and starts to charge him according to how much "actions" he performed with those users. There is no regular monthly subscriptions and I wouldn't like to ask users to "pay ahead" because they will run out of credits and I'll need to have them load some more = very difficult.

Answer (score 1):

If you think to bill the user after the monthly usage of the service, you cannot do that. In App Purchase is a form of payment in advance, so you can ask the user to pay initially for a certain amount of service (e.g.: use the service for N hours) and then decrease the number of available amount until it reaches zero, after that the user will be requested to purchase a new amount of such a service to continue to use it and so on.
You can do that using In App Purchase "consumable" in apps. But the user should buy the items before and not after the usage of your service.
Of course nothing prevents you to give some "credit" to the user and then ask the user to pay back this credit using in app purchase. This is closer to what you need but of course nobody can prevent the user to delete and re-install the app to reset his/her credit.

Another possibility is for you to introduce in-app subscriptions: but they are based on time, so you can ask for 1-week or 1-month service, but you cannot control the amount of service used in this month (in theory you could add a monthly cap, but I'm not sure this would be accepted by Apple as the idea behind subscription is that you pay for full usage in the subscription period).

Comment: Thanks. Actually the questions is if I MUST do that. Based on what I originally asked, can I implement my own charging mechanism or use a 3rd party SDK and still have my app approved? On other words when am I allowed to charge users NOT through in-app and refrain from paying the 30% commission?

Comment: Any purchase done inside an iOS app must be done via in app purchase.

Comment: So that means I can't charge my users at the end of the month according to the amount they owe me? What if I implement the credt card collection page as an external HTML and browse to it through the app?

Comment: You can collect money via external HTML but you cannot access it through the app. You can open your HTML using Mobile Safari instead, ask for the payment and then provide a login to the app. This should be legitimate but it's like entering in a mine field. Many apps already collect payments outside an iOS app but as far as I know these are famous apps (Dropbox, Skype, Amazon Kindle). In theory you can check your service usage and billing using a login system, but in such case I would recommend you to offer a minimum free service to avoid to see your app rejected because of "limited use".